# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am facing a problem with using one of my function.In which line there is the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` .

### My function is:

```
function hexConvert(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    delete(parts[0]);   //The error is in this line
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

### And The code when i am using that the error is consoling:-

```
var btn = $(".btn-3d");
btn.each(function(index, elem) {

    var bgColor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    hexConvert(bgColor);
    $(this).css({
        'box-shadow': '0px 4px 0px 0px' + ColorLuminocity(color, -0.1)
    });
});
```

Can any one help me to understant it?And get the solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` can return `null` (if there's no match), but you're not checking to see whether that happened before calling `delete(parts[0]);`

It's unclear to me why you *want* to delete that entry from the returned array (I'd probably use `shift`), but if you do (or if you use `shift`), you'll need a `null` guard:

```
function hexConvert(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    if (!parts) {     // <====
        color = null; // <====
        return;       // <====
    }                 // <====
    delete parts[0];  // <==== `delete` isn't a function, no need for parens
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

and then when you use it:

```
hexConvert(bgColor);
if (color) {
    $(this).css({
        'box-shadow': '0px 4px 0px 0px' + ColorLuminocity(color, -0.1)
    });
}
```

---

Side note: It's a really bad idea ot have `hexConvert` work with a global variable. Instead, have it *return* the result:

```
function hexConvert(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    if (!parts) {     // <====
        return null;  // <====
    }                 // <====
    delete parts[0];  // <==== `delete` isn't a function, no need for parens
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    return '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

and then when you use it:

```
var color = hexConvert(bgColor);
if (color) {
    $(this).css({
        'box-shadow': '0px 4px 0px 0px' + ColorLuminocity(color, -0.1)
    });
}
```